# c# httpcontent "400 - Bad Request" if string contains newline character

Tags: json, wpf, string, rest, special-characters

I am running into some kind of trouble communicating with a restful service from my .Net WPF application (.Net 4.5), in particular when sending a "PUT" request with some json data.

FYI: The restful service is running under Python Flask.

The method I use the following method to send request to the restful service:

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encodedCredentials);
http.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
// Add an Accept header for JSON format.
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpContent content = new StringContent(jDataString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

When I submit usual string, all works just fine. But I am having trouble as soon as the string contains line breaks.

Using:

```
mytring.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "")
```

works, my string is then accepted by the restful service.

Unfortunately, this is not acceptable, because I want to be able to retrieve line breaks.

I hence tried approaches like:

```
mytring.Replace("\n", "\\n").Replace("\r", "\\r")
```

or even with a inside-character to make sure I recognize the pattern:

```
mytring.Replace("\n", "\\+n").Replace("\r", "\\+r")
```

In both cases, my parsed string looks fine, but isn't accepted by the restful service.

Below two examples - the first version is accepted, not the second and third...

```
"XML_FIELD": "<IDs><Id Type=\"System.Int32\" Value=\"7\" /></IDs>"
"XML_FIELD": "<IDs>\r\n<Id Type=\"System.Int32\" Value=\"20\" />\r\n</IDs>"
"XML_FIELD": "<IDs>\+r\+n<Id Type=\"System.Int32\" Value=\"20\" />\+r\+n</IDs>"
```

Thanks in advance for the help!!
Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it...

The issue was coming from "\r\n" character which were coming directly from my DB...

Anyway, change to perform is for SERIALIZATION is

```
mySerializedString.Replace("\r\n", "\n")
                  .Replace("\n", "\\n")
                  .Replace("\r", "\\r")
                  .Replace("\'", "\\'")
                  .Replace("\"", "\\\"")
                  .Replace("\t", "\\t")
                  .Replace("\b", "\\b")
                  .Replace("\f", "\\f");
```

And to de-serialize do the inverse:

```
myDeSerializedString.Replace("\\n", "\n")
                    .Replace("\\r", "\r")
                    .Replace("\\'", "\'")
                    .Replace("\\\"", "\"")
                    .Replace("\\t", "\t")
                    .Replace("\\b", "\b")
                    .Replace("\\f", "\f");
```

NOTE: in the process, we loose "\r\n" characters (which are replaced by "\n").